# How to define a local variable in EB GUIDE scripts

Tags: local-variables

I tried to define a local variable in an EB GUIDE script. The GUIDE TF documentation says that the "let" keyword defines variables, but the compiler shows an error after the definition of the variable.

This applies to EB GUIDE 6.8 and the GUIDE TF documentation. When commenting out the definition of the variable, no error is shown. There is no example in the documentation, it only says that "let" defines a local variable.

```
{
    let v:x = 5;
    false // error in this line: "no viable alternative at input 'function(v:arg0::bool)"
}
```

The definition of a local variable should be possible with the let keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EB GUIDE Studio 6.8 scripts, the declaration of local variables must be followed by the keyword `in` and an expression or scope in which the variable is used.

```
{
    let v:x = 5
    in
    {
        // code that uses v:x
    }
}
```

Additionally to the GUIDE TF documentation, there is also the [documentation](https://www.elektrobit.com/ebguide/documentation/) of the Studio and a script reference card (cheat sheet) that contain some examples.